# regular expression to read a line separated by quotation marks and semicolon

Tags: java, regex, converters, readfile

For example, I have one line of code:

```
"12345";"ISBN345";"8"
```

I want to write a regular expression to extract 12345, ISBN345, 8.

How do I write this regular expression?

**updated:sorry.**

I did not make it clear. There are my real data :

> "276729";"052165615X";"3"

(my data has many lines and this line is only an example). I want to extract `276729`(user id) as one element, `052165615X`(book number) as one, `3` (book rating) as one(that means we need to match with the regular expression three times per line,so I can create three objects each time we read one line) but not extract `276729 052165615X 3` at one time

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? There are other more concise ways of splitting that string, eg String's split method

Comment: He'd have to clean up the string, i.e. remove stuff with a split.

Comment: There are many cases that you shouldn't trust your `String.split()`. Can you imagine having a semicolon in the second field?. But if the data consistent, I would also go with split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"([^"]+)"(;"([^"]+)")*
```

`[^"]+` will match a non-empty sequence of non-quote characters. You can switch `+` to `*` if the strings can be empty.

This entire regex  will a one quote sequence of not-quotes followed by zero or more quoted sequences separated by semicolons.

Comment: sorry. I did not make it clear. There are my real data : "276729";"052165615X";"3"(my data has many lines and this line is only an example). I want to extract 276729(user id) as one element, 052165615X(book number) as one, 3 (book rating) as one(that means we need to match with the regular expression three times per line,so I can create three objects each time we read one line) but not extract 276729 052165615X 3 at one time.

Comment: In that case you'd just expand the regex to replace the second capture group: `"([^"]+)";"([^"]+)";"([^"]+)"` That will give you a capture group for each string. I think you're better off using one regex with three capture groups than writing three regexes each with one.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems "([^"]+)";"([^"]+)";"([^"]+)" will match the entire string instead of just contents inside the quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Will match and split into num, num, letters, num

```
"(\d+)";"(\d+)(.+)";"(\d+)"
```

Option 2: Will match and split into num, numletters, num

```
"(\d+)";"(\d+.+)";"(\d+)"
```

Comment: That's an example, not every case. OP says nothing about numbers so I don't think `\d*` is appropriate, if the numbers were required it should also be `\d+`.

Comment: sorry. I did not make it clear. There are my real data : "276729";"052165615X";"3"(my data has many lines and this line is only an example). I want to extract 276729(user id) as one element, 052165615X(book number) as one, 3 (book rating) as one(that means we need to match with the regular expression three times per line,so I can create three objects each time we read one line) but not extract 276729 052165615X 3 at one time

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems "(\d+)";"(\d+.+)";"(\d+)" will match the whole string instead of just the contents inside the quotation marks. For example,I only want to extract 276729 instead of "278729"; .

Comment: @user3369592 I'm surprised this is your accepted answer. This wont work on your first example; this requires the second field start with numbers. As to the not matching question please post the js you are running.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs "There are my real data" is not very clear. Nothing in this question is. However I presume he/she doesn't want a regex for 1 line of code. From what I can decipher field one will always be an int, field three will also always be an int, and field two will vary. User3369592, is this true?

Comment: @chris85 Agreed. I try not to decipher what people really want but give the answer the ask for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it for you.

`"(\d+)";"(.*?)";"(\d+)"`

Presuming the first and third values are always numbers, and only numbers. The second value seems like it could be anything so `.*?` will allow everything to be there until the first double quote it encounters.